# gcloud functions: How to include local javascript helper files during deployment?

Tags: javascript, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy certain google cloud functions.
To keep things modular, I'm using some common JS files, that I include into every main GCF file.
It works fine locally.

But when I try to deploy, I get the dependency error, because it can't find the "common" JS files.

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3,
> message=Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
>
> Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
>
> Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../common/utils'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use have a `.gcloudignore` file at the root of your project. Then use the `!<folder_to_include>` to tell gcloud beta functions deploy which files to include with your deployment. In your case, include `!common/utils/**`

Documentation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore